# javascript on asp button control

Tags: c#, javascript

i am using asp button control to call a javascript function. but it is not working. it is showing an error
i am calling javascript function as:

```
 <asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="rock()" />
```

the javascript function is as:

```
function rock() {
   var username = prompt("what is your name?", "please enter your name here");

   if (username) {
       alert("nice to meet you," + username + ".");
    }
}
```

is there any way to call javascript function on asp button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` links to a server method, you want `onclientclick`.  If you had a simple HTML control which was not a server control, you can use `onclick` but it has a different meaning when it's an ASP.net control.

Fixed code:

```
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclientclick="rock()" />
```

Comment: it means that there are different events for every control in asp.how do i came to know about all of them..

Comment: @kawade with practise, you will get to know them all!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
onclick="rock()"
```

To:

```
onclientclick="rock()"
```

Depending on your code, you may need to set `CausesPostback = false;`